# Holomorphic sections that lead to the original parameterization of the gauged STU model

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, research-level, gauge, supergravity

The original action, given in [9903214](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903214v2), comes from the $\mathcal{N} = 2$ abelian truncation of the maximal $\mathcal{N} = 8$, $SO(8)$ gauged supergravity that can be obtained from $S^
7$
reduction of 11d supergravity.
Since I was wondering how this model fits into the general
framework of $\mathcal{N} = 2$ gauged supergravity, I did a search and found [1712.01849](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01849).
In appendix A they summarize some choices for the holomorphic sections:

A.1 Cveti$\mathrm{\check{c}}$ et al. gauge

A.2 Cacciatori-Klemm gauge

A.3 Pufu-Freedman gauge

A.4 Hristov-Vandoren gauge

They claim that using A.1 or A.2 the general action reduces to the gauged STU model action given in [9903214](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903214v2). But that's not true. The scalar potential is ok, but the resultant period matrix is different.
After some minor modifications and trial and error I got these holomorphic sections that work:
$$X^0=\sqrt{i z_1 z_2 z_3}, \quad\frac{X^1}{X^0}=-\frac{1}{z_2 z_3}, \quad\frac{X^2}{X^0}=-\frac{1}{z_1 z_3}, \quad\frac{X^3}{X^0}=-\frac{1}{z_1 z_2}$$
$$z_k=\chi_k+i e^{-\varphi_k}, \ \ \text{for } k\in\{1,2,3\}$$
I'm interested in knowing whether this choice has been considered before in the literature.

Has anyone seen the holomorphic sections I have found before?

Is there any reference with a choice of holomorphic sections that correctly reproduces the gauged STU model action given
in eqn. (B.7) of [9903214](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9903214v2)?